# Derivative of MSE Cost Function

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, mathematics

The gradient descent:

$\theta_{t+1}=\theta_t-a\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}J(\theta)$

But specifically about $J$ cost function (Mean Squared Error) partial derivative:

Consider that: $h_\theta(x)=\theta_0+\theta_1x$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}J(\theta) = \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}\frac{1}{2}(h_{\theta}(x)-y)^2$

$\ \ \ \ \   \ \ \ \ \   \ \ =2\frac{1}{2}(h_{\theta}(x)-y)*\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}(h_{\theta}(x)-y)$

$\ \ \ \ \   \ \ \ \ \   \ \ = (h_{\theta}(x)-y)*\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}(\sum_{i=0}^{n}\theta_ix_i-y_i)$

$\ \ \ \ \ \  \ \  \ \  \ \  = (h_{\theta}(x)-y)x_j$

It´s not clear to me how $x_j$ is calculated:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}(\sum_{i=0}^{n}\theta_ix_i-y) = x_j  $

**Can anyone help me to understand in detail this part of the partial derivative?**
*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Welcome to Data Science SE. Could you please link the source material and explain context? The answer is relatively simple though . . .

Comment: Thanks for answering. @NeilSlater, the context is the process of training an artificial neural network, specifically when weights are updated. The best weights minimizes a given cost function (J(θ) in my question).   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think the derivation you have given does not work for all the params of a general neural network, but only for the last layer, or in the case of linear regression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any term $f$ that is not a function of $\theta_j$ in any equation will have a partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}(f) = 0$. Importantly, no $x_i$, $y$ or $\theta_{i \ne j}$ depend in any way upon $\theta_j$, so they are effectively constants when figuring out the partial derivative. This is also true for any function of them, provided that also does not depend on $\theta_j$.

So for example $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}(f(y)) = 0$,  $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}(f(y)\theta_j) = f(y)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}(f(y)\theta_j^2) = 2f(y)\theta_j$

From this:

> $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}(\sum_{i=0}^{n}\theta_ix_i-y) = x_j  $

When $i \ne j$, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}(\theta_ix_i-y) = 0$, because no term inside the brackets depends on $\theta_j$.

When $i = j$, then  $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}(\theta_jx_j-y) = x_j$. Only the term $\theta_jx_j$ depends on $\theta_j$, and it is a linear multiplication.